# How to change a form's CSS class without affecting FormController.$pristine?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

## Use Case

Using AngularJS, I have a form with a toggle button - using the single toggle button from ui.bootstrap.buttons. This toggle button exists within the form itself.

The problem is that by toggling this button, it sets `$pristine` to false because the state of the form has changed. Unfortunately, `$pristine` is also used to disable/enable other UI components. So toggling the button changes the state of the other UI components as well.

Moving the toggle outside of `ng-form` will fix the problem, but in this particular case, I'd like to avoid that because it'll require some nasty CSS to fix the placement of the button.

The goal of this is to change the front-end by switching CSS rules when clicking this toggle button. In this particular project, it converts the front-end from using a grid view to a numbered list view.

### Questions

- Is it possible to create a toggle without affecting $pristine?

### Code

Here is a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LNC9C/) that is an overly simplified version of my use case. I used a checkbox instead of a toggle button, but they both do the same thing.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" ng-class="view">
    <ng-form role="form" name="myForm" >
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="view" ng-model="view"
          ng-true-value="list" ng-false-value="grid"
          />
        <p>
            Is myForm pristine? {{ myForm.$pristine }}
        </p>
    </ng-form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.view = 'grid';   
}
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 1em;
}

.list {
    border-color: red;
}

.grid {
    border-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-form to create nested form contexts for separate validation rules.

Based upon the plnkr found in this [blog post](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/03/angular-js-validating-form-elements-in.html) I updated it to show the idea with a $pristine flag too here in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XMYPJntAemAmpPTkVFlS?p=preview)

I know this is based upon ng-repeat but it explains the idea of nested form contexts nicely.

Comment: Wow that was simple! I forgot you could nest ng-forms.